# Running a Java Program having two Classes

Tags: java, inner-classes

I would like to know how could I execute this java program by rectifying the errors.

The code is:

```
import java.io.*;
class start
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      System.out.println("STARTING JAVA PROGRAM");
   }
}
class finish
{
   System.out.println("FINISH");
}
```

Error that was produced by executing this program is:

```
D:\Downloads\PRO>javac start.java

start.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
System.out.println("FINISH");
start.java:10: error: illegal start of type
System.out.println("FINISH");
```

Can we allow two classes in a java program?
Could anyone help me.

Comment: We can have two class in a java program. But here in your case you have written System.out..... outside a initialization block/method/static block/constructor and this is not allowed in java

Comment: @PrakharAsthana:Oh.I've know updated the post.

Comment: Maybe you also want to use a development environment like Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `System.out.println()` in class level.

```
class finish{
 System.out.println("FINISH"); // you can't do this.
}
```

You can use inside a method.

```
class finish{
 public void myMethod(){
  System.out.println("FINISH"); // now this is inside a method.
 }
}
```

You can use following way too. Put inside a `non-static initializers` or `static block`

```
class finish{ 
 { // non-static initializers
  System.out.println("FINISH"); // now this is inside a block.
 }
}
```

There are more you can use `System.out.println()` inside a constructor too.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of the latter one (class with statement in block without method)? When does it get executed?

Comment: @Thomas it is a Java class with a `non-static initializers`.This will be executed before every constructor, but after the call to super()

Comment: @Ruchira Gayan Ranaweera:But as you told I've placed the `System.out.println` statement inside a method but still it's not displaying "FINISH".

Comment: @justin putting `System.out.println` inside a method will not give you "FINISH". you need to call the method. eg: `public class Start {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("STARTING JAVA PROGRAM");
        Finish finish=new Finish();
        finish.myMethod();
    }
}

class Finish {

    public void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("FINISH");
    }
}
`

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera:Oh.I've called the method but again error occurs saying :`error: invalid method declaration; return type required`.Code I've added to program(more specifically in class finish) is method definition + method();(function call).Should we need to add a visiblity modifier for the method or is there any other problem?

Comment: @justin please show me your method in `Finish` class. seems to be you missed the `return` type of the method. make it `void`.

Comment: @Ruchira Gayan Ranaweera:I couldn't read your previous comment.Okay.But why can't the main method call the class finish?I've learned that main method is declared static so that it could create the objects of other classes.

Comment: @justin try this. `public class Start { public static void main(String args[]) { System.out.println("STARTING JAVA PROGRAM"); Finish finish=new Finish(); finish.myMethod(); } } class Finish { public void myMethod(){ System.out.println("FINISH"); } }`

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera:I'll show you the class finish:class finish
{
public void method()
{
System.out.println("FINISH");
}
method();
}Is there any problem?

Comment: @justin yes, It will not even compile. what is `method()`? . use proper method declaration. you can use `class finish { public void method() { System.out.println("FINISH"); }}`

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera:Thanks.That code worked.But can we call a method in another class without calling it's constructor?

Comment: @justin if that method is static you can call it by `className.method()` (with out creating a instance). else you have to instantiate a class.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera:I've made the method static and I've placed the method call in class finish.But still it says:`error: <identifier> expected`.Is there any problem?

Comment: @justin you got skype? or gtalk?, This comment section already very lengthy. I can explain you there.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera:It's not available now.But could you rather update the post containing two classes start and finish in which I would like to call the method from class finish and have the static main function in class start.

Answer (score 0):

You cant write System.out.println() inside a class directly,
You need a method or constructor by which you can call,by creating object of that class and then calling corresponding method,

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question that you required two classes in one file and want to call method of another class from the class which contain main method.
You can write code as show below to call method of other class.

```
class start
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      System.out.println("STARTING JAVA PROGRAM");
      //finish.myMethod();
      finish f = new finish(); //this will call myMethod() from static block
   }
}
class finish
{  
    static
    {
       myMethod();
    }
    public static void myMethod()
    {
       System.out.println("FINISH");
    }
}
```

**OutPut :**

```
STARTING JAVA PROGRAM
FINISH
```

Comment: :Thanks.That's really a good answer but I would like to see if I can run the method from class finish instead of class start using this same code.Could you say whether this is possible.

Comment: you mean to say if i have method let say `A` in class start than you want to call method `A` from class finish ?

Comment: :I didn't meant like that.I would rather want both i.e method's `A` definition and method's `A` call to be in the same class finish.Also the class start should have the static main method.Can we write a program like this?

Comment: @justin than could you call that method will execute if you place it in same class ?

Comment: :yeah that's right.But then how does main method call the method `A`.I think main method also doesn't have any information about method `A` while it calls method `A` isn't it?Then why couldn't the class in which the method `A` exsist call the method `A`?

Comment: :I've read your updated answer and that's what I was expecting.But could you tell me why we can only call a method from static block using a class constructor?Is there any problem in calling a method from non-static block using class constructor?

Comment: np problem in placing method in not-static block. you can remove static and use only initialize block to call method.

Comment: :But I tried to do as you said:
class start
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
System.out.println("STARTING JAVA PROGRAM");
}
finish f=new finish();
f.method();
}
class finish
{
public void method()
{
System.out.println("FINISHING JAVA PROGRAM");
}
}.But it says:`error: <identifier> expected`.Can you say whether this code is correct?

Comment: place your code `finish f=new finish(); f.method();` inside main method.

Comment: :that's right.But could you say why we can't place the code outside main method.

Comment: first you say what is the use of placing code outside main ? because it illegal in java or java syntax does not allowed it.